# Can I use a locator specific to Angular1 in Protractor code which is testing a hybrid app?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am responsible for updating Protractor tests to run against a hybrid  application which is in the process of being upgraded from Angular1 to Angular2.  I wrote a complete test suite when the application was Angular1-only, before the upgrade to Angular2 had started.  I work only on the test automation; I have no control over the actual application code.

Now, there are many places where the existing test code uses locators for things which are not in Angular2, specifically by.repeater().  This test code runs against portions of the application which have not been upgraded to Angular2, and which still use the "ng-repeat=..." construction in the code.

Is it expected that I would need to change the locators used to something like by.css() as soon as any parts of the application are in Angular2, or should those locators work as long as the piece of the application being tested is still written in Angular1?